# Apache logs with WSGI ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: django, apache, wsgi, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

According to [Bitnami's documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/django/get-started/deploy-django-project/#approach-a-bitnami-installations-using-system-packages), I've followed their desired steps

1. Enable WSGI configuration for the Django application
2. Enable predefined virtual hosts for a Django project
3. Configure Django project for public access
4. Create a custom virtual host

In the end of the documentation, it states

> You should now be able to browse to your project at
> http://SERVER-IP/PROJECT/APP.

In this case

SERVER-IP: 35.178.211.120

PROJECT: tutorial

APP: hello_world

If I go to the following locations

- http://35.178.211.120/
- http://35.178.211.120/tutorial/
- http://35.178.211.120/tutorial/hello_world

I get **Internal Error 500**. If I check the logs /home/bitnami/stack/apache2/logs

> [Tue Sep 29 18:33:16.858668 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1473] [remote
> 109.51.236.49:57609] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PROJECT'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that specific documentation it says to use similar code to

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/PROJECT')
os.environ.setdefault("PYTHON_EGG_CACHE", "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/myproject/egg_cache")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "PROJECT.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Yet, one can't forget to substitute PROJECT with the name of the Django project. For instance, if your project is named tutorial, then replace PROJECT with tutorial

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "tutorial.settings")
```

Then if you go to your instance IP address, like http://35.178.211.120/, you'll see

[image: Django production ready app]